# Where Linux kernel(3.4.34) open port on nat device?

Tags: linux, ftp, kernel, port, nat

I use an Linux Server for nat device.
Currently it looks like [PC1,2,3]--[Linux]--[Internet]

There is no issue at all , but I'm curious about , when I open a service (ex: FTP WWW ) on my PC1 , did my [Linux] also opened a port service on it ?

I did trace code for the

CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP
CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP

but I cant find related code about port open.

Thanks for your read.

Comment: No, opening a port in the PC firewall doesn't do anything to Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various techniques used the make a router/firewall automatically forward ports to its clients. For example there are some protocols like: [IGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol), [NAT-PMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol) et similia.
But those protocol need to be implemented both on router and on client. So automatic port-mapping won't work out of the box in many cases.
The lines in kernel config you are referring to `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP` `CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP` are used for another reason: due to the fact that FTP protocol use two different tcp streams for comunication (one of which does not have to be "listened" by the server) your firewall needs extra "effort" to track the connection and act accordingly.